# Weird output with the number of active goroutines

Tags: go, channel

I have trying to learn channels by running small programs. I don't understand the below program coz it's giving a weird output:

```
func squares(c chan int) {
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        num := <-c
        fmt.Println(num * num)
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 3)
    go squares(c)

    c <- 1
    c <- 2
    c <- 3
    c <- 4

    fmt.Println(runtime.NumGoroutine())
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Println(runtime.NumGoroutine())
}
```

While executing this program, I see that 1st it prints the number of active goroutines as 2. Then a second later, its giving as 1. This is really strange.

I checked few blogs, but couldn't understand. So what actually changed in a second that the goroutine stopped working?

Comment: The second goroutine "stops working" at some point when the work is done.  You've given it a very short task to do, it's not surprising that your computer can complete this in less than a second.

Comment: runtime.NumGoroutine reports all goroutines, not only the ones you start, but also those the runtime itslef uses. There is nothing to see or learn here.

Answer (score 4):

There is no guarantee on the ordering of goroutines. Based on your observation, it looks like after writing to the channel, the main goroutine continues and prints the active goroutines as two, and then the `squares` goroutine runs and completes.

It is possible that you also get 1 from the first call to get the number of goroutines. This would happen if the `squares` goroutine runs immediately after the main goroutine writes to the channel. You can force this execution by adding a sleep call right after writing to the channel but before getting the number of goroutines.

Answer (score 1):

Your 2nd goroutine receives the 4 values, prints them and exits (when `squares` returns) almost immediately.  You're lucky it's still running at the first call to `NumGoRoutines`.

BTW instead of learning by experimenting I suggest you read about the language. Just because something works when you try it does not mean, especially when concurrency is involved, that it is the correct way and will always work.  Alternatively, use the race detector to show any data races.

Answer (score 0):

1. Let me enforce the ordering, so you don't even need to count the number of goroutines, try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/afogfhiHmMv):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    ch := make(chan int)
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for n := range ch {
            fmt.Println(n)
        }
    }()

    ch <- 1
    ch <- 2
    ch <- 3
    ch <- 4

    fmt.Println("NumGoroutine =", runtime.NumGoroutine()) // 2
    close(ch)
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("NumGoroutine =", runtime.NumGoroutine()) // 1
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
NumGoroutine = 2
4
NumGoroutine = 1
```

Notes:

1. Using unbuffered channel forces **one to one** synchronization of **writing** to the channel and **reading** from the channel.
2. Explicitly close the channel to exit the `for` loop.
3. Using `wg.Done()` explicitly signals the end of the goroutine, so `wg.Wait()` waits for it.

---

2. Let me **unfold** the `for` loop first:

```
func squares(c chan int) {
    num := <-c
    fmt.Println(num * num)
    num = <-c
    fmt.Println(num * num)
    num = <-c
    fmt.Println(num * num)
    num = <-c
    fmt.Println(num * num)
}
func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 3)
    go squares(c)
    c <- 1
    c <- 2
    c <- 3
    c <- 4
    fmt.Println("NumGoroutine =", runtime.NumGoroutine())
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
    fmt.Println("NumGoroutine =", runtime.NumGoroutine())
}
```

Now let's run it:
Since you are using **buffered channel** of 3, these 3 lines run fast (meaning without waiting for the channel synchronisation - just appends `1, 2, 3` to the channel's buffer):

```
    c <- 1
    c <- 2
    c <- 3
```

And depending on the OS and CPU load the consumer goroutine may consumes them all or not,
at this `c <- 4` point, we have two scenarios:

1. The channel is full: so the `main` goroutine waits for the channel synchronization.
2. The channel has one (or more) free location(s): so the `c <- 4` runs fast and just puts  the `4` inside the channel's buffer (without waiting for channel synchronization).

Now after this `c <- 4` point, we have two scenarios too:

1. The other goroutine consumes the `4` and exits, so we have only **one** `main` goroutine.
2. The other goroutine **not** consumes the `4`, so we have **two** goroutines.